# GUI freezes after os.system call

Tags: python, pyqt4

My problem is with os.system. Until it finishes formatting, GUI freezes, and I can't fix it.

```
class ImageDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("Recursos/main.ui",self) 
        self.connect(self.ui.proteger_Button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self,
                     QtCore.SLOT("protec()"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def protec(self):
        self.USB = "G:"
        comando = "format %s /fs:ntfs /q /v:test /y" %(self.USB)
        os.system(comando)`

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = ImageDialog()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you could thread the `os.system` call, since you don't check the return of it (not stored in any visible variable). This will allow your gui to continue its main loop, preventing a freeze of the window.

Comment: Also, you may want to check your indentation of your code, as it looks like you may be mixing tabs & spaces.

Comment: Run the process in a `QThread`.

Comment: thanks! how to QThread with os.system. i don't know

Comment: a basic example  please!

Comment: I think something like subprocess.Popen() might be a better choice. There should be examples online how to do asynchronous process I/O in pure python, without being Qt-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest fix in your case is to add:

```
from threading import Thread
```

to your imports list, and then:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def protec(self):
    self.USB = "G:"
    comando = "format %s /fs:ntfs /q /v:test /y" %(self.USB)
    t = Thread(target = lambda: os.system(comando))
    t.start()
```

This way the GUI thread will not get stuck waiting for the external process to finish.

You could probably remember the `t`'s value and manage it in some way, so the number of threads running won't increase without limit, in case the external commands will hang, or run for a long time.

Note that it is not a good way to handle external processes. [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module is recommended for this.